# Can't install M2MQTT Nuget package to Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, nuget

When installing the Nuget package for M2MQTT 4.3 to my Xamarin.iOS project, I get the following error:

> Could not install package 'M2Mqtt 4.3.0'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework.

However, 4.2 works fine. I have seen this error pop up for some other packages too, and my Nuget is up to date. This error shows up when I try to install in VS2017 on Windows and also on Visual Studio for Mac.

Should it be possible to build the package myself from source, and if so, what do I need to change to make it compatible (assuming that the library doesn't actually use part of .NET that Xamarin.iOS doesn't support)?

The reason I need to update is that on 4.2 I get the following error when trying to create a MqttClient:

> The type 'IPAddress' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>   You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=3.9.0.0...'

and my hope is that this error will be resolved in the newest version.

Comment: I suggest you these NuGet packages for using the MQTT protocol with Xamarin.IOs. 1. https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Mqtt/0.4.9-experimental , 2. https://www.nuget.org/packages/M2MqttDotnetCore/ , 3. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MQTTnet/2.5.3-rc1

Comment: The NuGet package you're referring to is not Xamarin compatible